# UINavigation in UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationformsh

Not sure if someone can help me.

I am trying to create a UIModalPresentationFormSheet with navigation. I can load the view but i am not sure how to setup the navigation controller so when a row in the tableloaded loads the edit screen. At the moment it loads a uiviewcontroller with a tableview on it from the main screen. I need to allow editing on the table to add/edit delete records. When the user clicks either add or edit a new uiviewcontroller(detail view) is pushed to screen. It would be better if i had a navigation controller right? but i do need the edit buttons and back on the nave bar.

I think i have the button adding working its more just setting up the navigationcontroller

RootViewController - TableView select a row it loads the DetailViewController

DetailViewContoller - DetailView - Contains a button that loads the FormView as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet see link below.

FormView - Loads UIModalPresentationFormSheet
Formsheet - Tableview with data in it. Editing this data loads the FormDetailView
http://www.bronron.com/iphoneDev/screen1.png

FormDetail view - viewcontroller with save and cancel buttons on nave bar
http://www.bronron.com/iphoneDev/screen2.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance

Thanks,
Azz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the UIModalPresentationFormSheet Formsheet, simply add:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:/*the formsheet*/];
```

Then just add `navController` to the modal view, instead of the root view.  Then you will be able to add buttons and push viewControllers, etc.

Comment: Something like this?

SystemPickerViewController *controller = [[[SystemPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SystemPickerViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller.delegate = self;

controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

controller.originalSystemName = currentSystem;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: Yes, thats it; except change the last line to: `self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];`

Comment: I did that and it doesnt seem to load the mini view (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) it loads like a normal tableview eg the full size of screen

Comment: Do i need to create a new UINavigation controller for the UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what your asking.  But that sounds right

Answer (score 0):

Apple has ample documentation on these basic topics.  Have a look at the [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) and [Table Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;`